# Replace text appearing on webpage via ajax

Tags: ajax, nginx, replace

I've got a website with products catalog using ajax pagination. I want to replace  text on all product cards. First product cards (2 rows) are already rendered on page, but next product cards are loading via ajax while scrolling page down.

I can't change websites source code, so the question is it possible to make a replacement for example via Nginx (smth. like 'sub_filter')? Maybe other variants?

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_filter_types *;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter "foo" "bar";
```

In case if you are using gzip on backend, you have to remove it or add

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).